# Differential Equations and Newton's 2nd Law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I started writing out the basic equation for Newton's 2nd Law with the weight and F=ma but I have no idea how to continue with this question given the information! Help would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Available on chegg!!! Lol!!!! Or related problems , If it's not a Conjecture though.

Comment: MSE rules are not followed , Plz provide some motivation of the problem and follow up in rough.Like What is your approach style.

Comment: Secondly!!! May it's a exam question and you are giving the exam right now ,who knows right?

Comment: This is not an exam question at all! Please help me. I actually don't understand how to use the information in this question beyond writing Newton's 2nd law.

Comment: Chegg E ache bhai (This is on Chegg)

Comment: Assuming that the mass is constant, Newton's Second law looks like 
$$
\sum F = m \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$